# How to upload animate GIF in rails with CarrierWave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, gif, animated-gif

I can't upload GIF image in rails. All uploaded images are converted to JPG.
Please help me, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

try white listing gif type

```
class MyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def extension_whitelist
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
end
```

Comment: This should keep it as-is without conversion, but keep in mind thumbnails won't be animated. You need to show the raw image.